# How to execute a JS script only once with cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I want to execute this script only the first time that the user see my website:

```
var applicationId = "MyAppID";
var clientKey = "MyClientKEY";
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
  window.parsepushnotification.setUp(applicationId, clientKey);

  //registerAsPushNotificationClient callback (called after setUp)
  window.parsepushnotification.onRegisterAsPushNotificationClientSucceeded = function() {
    alert('Verified!');
  };

  window.parsepushnotification.onRegisterAsPushNotificationClientFailed = function() {
    alert('Not verified, contact an admin.');
  };    
}, false);
```

What can I do?

I tried to use this cookie method but it doesn't work...

```
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
  var visited=getCookie("visited");
  if (visited != "") {
    // NOTHING BECAUSE THE USER VISITED THE PAGE
  } else {
    // EXECUTE JS SCRIPT ABOVE BECAUSE IS THE FIRST TIME THAT THE USER SEE THE PAGE
    setCookie("visited", ok, 30);
  }
}
```

So I don't understand why it doesn't work and I tried to read a lot of webpage to learn something about it...
Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Assuming the browsers you are targeting support it (IE8+), I would use `localStorage` instead of cookies. It's much simpler.

Comment: Is `setCookie("visited", ok, 30)` a typo? What is `ok`? Is that supposed to be the string `'ok'`?

Comment: The phrase "doesn't work" isn't very helpful to us. Do you get a JavaScript error in the console? If not, what specifically does the script do contrary to what you're expecting?

Comment: @levi how can I do this?

Comment: @Jacob "ok" is the value of the cookie. I want that when the user visit the page, he has a cookie that remember that he already visited the page so the JS script above doesn't execute.

Comment: @Jacob the result is that the script says always that I have the cookie inside but when I change the cookie name, it always says that the cookie is ok but I haven't set it!?

Do you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this in case it's the answer. This line:

```
setCookie("visited", ok, 30);
```

...may be the problem. I do not see an `ok` variable in your page. If you replace that with a string, it may work:

```
setCookie('visited', 'ok', 30);
```

Also, `toGMTString()` is deprecated; use `toUTCString()` instead.

Comment: function checkCookie() {
    var visited=getCookie("cookie");
    if (visited != "ok") {
        alert("Cookie OK");
    } else {
   alert("Creating the cookie...");
            setCookie('cookie', 'ok', 30);
    }
}

Comment: Isn't your if statement backwards? Should be `if (visited === 'ok')`. Currently, you're only setting the cookie to `'ok'` if it's already set to `'ok'`.

Comment: I already tried it but it always says "Creating the cookie..."... :/

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/jc3r9qjy/1/. If I run this once, it detects that the cookie does not exist. The second time, that it does. Are you just blocking cookies?

Comment: I don't no... I copied your code but it doesn't work!

Comment: Maybe it's what @Arm1stice says then. Or if you are running on a website, then maybe you have an ad blocker, browser setting, security software, etc. that is blocking cookies.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jacob and @Arm1stice!

Comment: I uploaded the page on my webserver and now it work great...
Maybe this was the problem! Ahahahah

Answer (score 1):

I sense you are trying to run in the browser off of a file on your computer. In order for this code to work and for the cookies to properly set, the page must be loaded from a webserver.

EDIT: 
Also, as Jacob said, you should be the cookie to have a non null value.

```
setCookie("visited", 'ok', 3);
```

instead of

```
setCookie("visited", ok, 3);
```